# How to add an empty column to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment

What's the easiest way to add an empty column to a pandas DataFrame object?  The best I've stumbled upon is something like

```py
df['foo'] = df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)
```

Is there a less perverse method?

Comment: Do you actually want a column containing empty strings or rather `N/A`?

Answer (score 752, accepted):

If I understand correctly, assignment should fill:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
>>> df["C"] = ""
>>> df["D"] = np.nan
>>> df
   A  B C   D
0  1  2   NaN
1  2  3   NaN
2  3  4   NaN
```

Comment: This answer just created new rows for me.

Comment: @logicbloke can you provide an example where this is happening?

Comment: @craymichael It's been a while but I believe I had number-indexed columns with no names and named rows and it just created a new row at the end.

Comment: If the `df` is empty, you may want to use `df['new'] = pd.Series()`  (see my answer below)

Comment: how to add multiple empty columns?

Comment: @logicbloke, i think if you have a series object then the answer provided creates new rows. but using .to_frame() to convert the series object to a pandas dataframe allows to use the method to insert new columns

Comment: similar attitude provided me with a warning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @M.Mariscal `df[["newcol1","newcol2","newcol3"]] = None`.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou - the `df[["newcol1","newcol2","newcol3"]] = None` causes KeyError: "['newcol1' 'newcol2' 'newcol3'] not in index" in pandas 0.19.2.

Comment: @sdbbs Pandas 0.19.2 is a fairly old version, I wouldn’t be surprised if it didn’t support this syntax.

Comment: @skippy-le-grand-gourou, this code will trigger a SettingWithCopyWarning 
 warning. Do this instead:

`df.loc[:, ["newcol1","newcol2","newcol3"]] = np.nan`

Answer (score 81):

To add to DSM's answer and building on [this associated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670/pandas-add-multiple-empty-columns-to-dataframe), I'd split the approach into two cases:

- Adding a single column: Just assign empty values to the new columns, e.g. `df['C'] = np.nan`
- Adding multiple columns: I'd suggest using the `.reindex(columns=[...])` [method of pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add the new columns to the dataframe's column index. This also works for adding multiple new rows with `.reindex(rows=[...])`. Note that newer versions of Pandas (v>0.20) allow you to specify an `axis` keyword rather than explicitly assigning to `columns` or `rows`.

Here is an example adding multiple columns:

```
mydf = mydf.reindex(columns = mydf.columns.tolist() + ['newcol1','newcol2'])
```

or

```
mydf = mydf.reindex(mydf.columns.tolist() + ['newcol1','newcol2'], axis=1)  # version > 0.20.0
```

You can also always concatenate a new (empty) dataframe to the existing dataframe, but that doesn't feel as pythonic to me :)

Comment: Example for `version >= 0.20.0` deletes the DataFrame and adds the new columns as rows. Example for `version < 0.20.0` works fine on Pandas Version `0.24.1`

Comment: @emunsing While searching for an answer to this question, I ultimately found your answer helpful. At first, however, it wasn't working for me as Pandas requires `, axis=1` in `version = 0.25`.  I attempted to modify your answer to include the updated version, but I was rejected by @kenlukas and @il_raffa.  I hope everyone struggling to understand why your response isn't working for them--like I was--at least comes across this comment.

Comment: @Griff - I've now updated my answer to be more accurate and explicit about version compatability issues. Thanks for highlighting this.

Answer (score 80):

I like:

```py
df['new'] = pd.Series(dtype='int')

# or use other dtypes like 'float', 'object', ...
```

If you have an empty dataframe, this solution makes sure that no new row containing only `NaN` is added.

Specifying `dtype` is not strictly necessary, however newer Pandas versions produce a `DeprecationWarning` if not specified.

Comment: This is the best way to insert a new column with predefined dtype.

Comment: Totally agree. If for any reason you need to size the new series to any given `df`, you can add `index=df.index`.

Answer (score 65):

an even simpler solution is:

```
df = df.reindex(columns = header_list)
```

where "header_list" is a list of the headers you want to appear.

any header included in the list that is not found already in the dataframe will be added with blank cells below.

so if

```
header_list = ['a','b','c', 'd']
```

then c and d will be added as columns with blank cells

Comment: More precisely, the columns will be added with NaNs.

Answer (score 44):

Starting with `v0.16.0`, [`DF.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) could be used to assign new columns (*single/multiple*) to a `DF`. These columns get inserted in alphabetical order at the end of the `DF`.

This becomes advantageous compared to simple assignment in cases wherein you want to perform a series of chained operations directly on the returned dataframe.

Consider the same `DF` sample demonstrated by @DSM:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
df
Out[18]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

df.assign(C="",D=np.nan)
Out[21]:
   A  B C   D
0  1  2   NaN
1  2  3   NaN
2  3  4   NaN
```

Note that this returns a copy with all the previous columns along with the newly created ones. In order for the original `DF` to be modified accordingly, use it like : `df = df.assign(...)` as it does not support `inplace` operation currently.

Comment: What is that datatype for C? I am trying to add by looping through a list of strings. But it does not use it.

Answer (score 12):

```
df["C"] = ""
df["D"] = np.nan
```

Assignment will give you this warning **SettingWithCopyWarning**:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

so its better to use **insert**:

```
df.insert(index, column-name, column-value)
```

**If this answer helps you don't forget to upvote**

Answer (score 7):

if you want to add column name from a list

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
a=['col1','col2','col3','col4']
for i in a:
    df[i]=np.nan
```

Answer (score 6):

@emunsing's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405540/7391480) is really cool for adding multiple columns, but I couldn't get it to work for me in python 2.7.  Instead, I found this works:

```
mydf = mydf.reindex(columns = np.append( mydf.columns.values, ['newcol1','newcol2'])
```

Comment: Please don't use Python 2.7...

Answer (score 6):

One can use `df.insert(index_to_insert_at, column_header, init_value)` to insert new column at a specific index.

```
cost_tbl.insert(1, "col_name", "")
```

The above statement would insert an empty Column after the first column.

Answer (score 4):

this will also work for multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C','D','E'])
df = df.join(df1, how="outer")

>>>df
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   NaN NaN NaN
1   2   3   NaN NaN NaN
2   3   4   NaN NaN NaN
```

Then do whatever you want to do with the columns
`pd.Series.fillna(),pd.Series.map()`
etc.

Comment: how efficient is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715082/what-is-the-running-time-big-o-order-of-pandas-dataframe-join

if you join on actual data it's O(n log(n)) , my assumption is since the df is empty,
max O(n)

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df['column'] = None #This works. This will create a new column with None type
df.column = None #This will work only when the column is already present in the dataframe
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of columns that you want to be empty, you can  use `assign`, then comprehension dict, then dict unpacking.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
>>> nan_cols_name = ["C","D","whatever"]
>>> df.assign(**{col:np.nan for col in nan_cols_name})

   A  B   C   D  whatever
0  1  2 NaN NaN       NaN
1  2  3 NaN NaN       NaN
2  3  4 NaN NaN       NaN
```

You can also unpack multiple dict in a dict that you unpack if you want different values for different columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
nan_cols_name = ["C","D","whatever"]
empty_string_cols_name = ["E","F","bad column with space"]
df = df.assign(**{
    **{col:np.nan for col in my_empy_columns_name}, 
    **{col:"" for col in empty_string_cols_name}
            }
         )
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code address the question "How do I add n number of empty columns to my existing dataframe". In the interest of keeping solutions to similar problems in one place, I am adding it here.

Approach 1 (to create 64 additional columns with column names from 1-64)

```
m = list(range(1,65,1)) 
dd=pd.DataFrame(columns=m)
df.join(dd).replace(np.nan,'') #df is the dataframe that already exists
```

Approach 2 (to create 64 additional columns with column names from 1-64)

```
df.reindex(df.columns.tolist() + list(range(1,65,1)), axis=1).replace(np.nan,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for I did not explain my answer really well at beginning. There is another way to add an new column to an existing dataframe.
1st step, make a new empty data frame (with all the columns in your data frame, plus a new or few columns you want to add) called df_temp
2nd step, combine the df_temp and your data frame.

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=(df_null.columns.tolist() + ['empty']))
df = pd.concat([df_temp, df])
```

It might be the best solution, but it is another way to think about this question.

the reason of I am using this method is because I am get this warning all the time:

```
: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["empty1"], df["empty2"] = [np.nan, ""]
```

great I found the way to disable the Warning

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: Ok so... make sure that when giving an answer please give some info on what is happening line by line of possible. Because the person asking the question won't learn from this will he? He will copy and paste and his code will work and he won't know why. So I suggest adding a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was looking for such a solution is simply to add spaces between multiple DFs which have been joined column-wise using the pd.concat function and then written to excel using xlsxwriter.

```
df[' ']=df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)
df_2 = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)                #worked but only once. 
# Note: df & df1 have the same rows which is my index. 
#
df_2[' ']=df_2.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)       #didn't work this time !!?     
df_4 = pd.concat([df_2,df_3],axis=1)
```

I then replaced the second lambda call with

```
df_2['']=''                                 #which appears to add a blank column
df_4 = pd.concat([df_2,df_3],axis=1)
```

The output I tested it on was using xlsxwriter to excel.
Jupyter blank columns look the same as in excel although doesnt have xlsx formatting.
Not sure why the second Lambda call didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple empty columns by directly assigning a list of values. Below is an example where column `C` is a column of empty strings and `D` is a column of NaNs.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [2, 3, 4]})
df[['C', 'D']] = ['', float('nan')]
```

[image: result1]

You can create multiple columns of a specific value by item assignment as well. Below is an example where columns `E`, `F` and `G` are initialized with NaN values.

```py
df[["E","F","G"]] = float('nan')

# this can be done using `assign` as well
df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(['E', 'F', 'G'], float('nan')))
```

If you're getting a SettingWithCopyWarning when creating a new column, that indicates that your dataframe was created from another dataframe using a filtering operation, so simply turning on copy-on-write mode (which is planned to be the default behavior by pandas 3.0) would silence that warning (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/19123103) for more info).

```py
pd.set_option('mode.copy_on_write', True)          # turn on CoW
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
df1 = df.query("A<3")
df1[['C', 'D']] = ['', float('nan')]
```