# Add multiple empty columns to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add multiple empty columns to a `DataFrame` from a list?

I can do:

```
df["B"] = None
df["C"] = None
df["D"] = None
```

But I can't do:

```
df[["B", "C", "D"]] = None
```

> `KeyError: "['B' 'C' 'D'] not in index"`

Comment: `None` is different to 0, but some answers are assuming it's equivalent. Also, assigning `None` will give a dtype of object, but assigning 0 will give a dtype of int.

Comment: Also you can't do `df[['B','C','D']] = None, None, None` or `[None, None, None]` or `pd.DataFrame([None, None, None])`

Comment: Related : the more general [How to add multiple columns to pandas dataframe in one assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-in-one-assignment)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I'd [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) using a DataFrame:

```
In [23]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
df

Out[23]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []

In [24]:    
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=list('BCD'))])

Out[24]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

So by passing a list containing your original df, and a new one with the columns you wish to add, this will return a new df with the additional columns.

---

Caveat: See the discussion of performance in the other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30943503/884640) and/or the comment discussions. `reindex` may be preferable where performance is critical.

Answer (score 125):

You could use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add new columns:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,1)), columns=['A'])

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   A
0  4
1  7
2  0
3  7
4  6

In [20]: df.reindex(columns=list('ABCD'))
Out[20]: 
   A   B   C   D
0  4 NaN NaN NaN
1  7 NaN NaN NaN
2  0 NaN NaN NaN
3  7 NaN NaN NaN
4  6 NaN NaN NaN
```

`reindex` will return a new DataFrame, with columns appearing in the order they are listed:

```
In [31]: df.reindex(columns=list('DCBA'))
Out[31]: 
    D   C   B  A
0 NaN NaN NaN  4
1 NaN NaN NaN  7
2 NaN NaN NaN  0
3 NaN NaN NaN  7
4 NaN NaN NaN  6
```

The `reindex` method as a `fill_value` parameter as well:

```
In [22]: df.reindex(columns=list('ABCD'), fill_value=0)
Out[22]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  4  0  0  0
1  7  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
3  7  0  0  0
4  6  0  0  0
```

Comment: After experimenting with a moderately large Data Frame (~2.5k rows for 80k columns), and this solution appears to be orders of magnitude faster than the accepted one.BTW is there a reason why this specific command does not accept an "inplace=True" parameter? df = df.reindex(...) appears to use up quite a bit of RAM.

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci: I recommend never using `inplace=True`. It doesn't do what most people think it does. Under the hood, an entirely new DataFrame is always created, and then the data from the new DataFrame is copied into the original DataFrame. That doesn't save any memory. So `inplace=True` is window-dressing without substance, and moreover, is misleadingly named. I haven't checked the code, but I expect `df = df.reindex(...)` requires at least 2x the memory required for `df`, and of course more when `reindex` is used to expand the number of rows.

Comment: @unutbu, nevertheless, it is useful when you are iterating containers,  e.g. a list or a dictionary, it would avoid the use of indexes that makes the code a bit more dirty...

Comment: @unutbu it is indeed a lot faster when i profiled my ~200 columns creation code, could you briefly explain why doing reindex is much faster than concat or simply setting multiple columns to a numpy array?

Answer (score 48):

If you **don't want to rewrite the name of the old columns**, then you can use reindex:

```
df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns.tolist(), 'new_column1', 'new_column2'], fill_value=0)
```

---

***Full example***:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,1)), columns=['A'])

In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   A
0  4
1  7
2  0

In [2]: df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns.tolist(), 'col1', 'col2'], fill_value=0)
Out[2]: 

   A  col1  col2
0  1     0     0
1  2     0     0
```

---

And, if you **already have a list** with the column names, :

```
In [3]: my_cols_list=['col1','col2']

In [4]: df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns.tolist(), *my_cols_list], fill_value=0)
Out[4]: 
   A  col1  col2
0  1     0     0
1  2     0     0
```

Answer (score 11):

Summary of alternative solutions:

```
columns_add = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

1. for loop:

   ```
   for newcol in columns_add:
       df[newcol]= None
   ```
2. dict method:

   ```
   df.assign(**dict([(_,None) for _ in columns_add]))
   ```
3. tuple assignment:

   ```
   df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = None, None, None
   ```

Comment: `df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(columns_add, None))` should also work

Answer (score 9):

Why not just use loop:

```
for newcol in ['B','C','D']:
    df[newcol]=np.nan
```

Comment: 0 is not the same value as None. Also, it'll force the dtype to integer, whereas None won't.

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of [Pandas broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954263/8973620):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1]})

df[['B', 'C']] = 2, 3
# df[['B', 'C']] = [2, 3]
```

Result:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
```

To add empty columns:

```
df[['B', 'C', 'D']] = 3 * [np.nan]
```

Result:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  1 NaN NaN NaN
1  1 NaN NaN NaN
2  1 NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use

```
df["B"], df["C"], df["D"] = None, None, None
```

or

```
df["B"], df["C"], df["D"] = ["None" for a in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the list of funny ways:

```
columns_add = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = df.assign(**dict(zip(columns_add, [0] * len(columns_add)))
```

Comment: 0 is not the same value as None. Also, it'll force the dtype to integer, whereas None won't.

Comment: Anyway you're missing a trailing fourth close-parenthesis.