# how to initialize multiple columns to existing pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I initialize multiple columns in a single instance in an existing pandas DataFrame object? I can initialize single column at an instance, this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}, dtype='int')
df['c'] = 0
```

but i cannot do something like:

```
df[['c','d']] = 0 or
df[['c']['d']] = 0
```

is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

I prefer this solution.

```
    df = df.assign(**{'c': 0, 'd': 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

i got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670/pandas-add-multiple-empty-columns-to-dataframe).

```
df.reindex(columns = list['cd'])
```

will do the trick.

actually it will be:

```
df.reindex(columns = list['abcd'])
```

Comment: Should be `df.reindex(columns = list('abcd')).fillna(0)`.

Comment: yes..actuall fillna(0) is what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: What you currently have will throw an error. Should be: `columns = list('abcd')` or `columns = ['a','b','c','d']` for the `columns` argument.

Comment: The solution from @fleurette is safer (no risk of deleting non-mentioned columns) and faster (as no fillna has to be applied afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

***`pd.concat`***

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(0, df.index, list('cd'))], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

***`join`***

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(0, df.index, list('cd')))
```

[image]