# How to add columns to an empty pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty `dataframe`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
```

for some reason I want to generate df2, another empty dataframe, with two columns 'a' and 'b'.

If I do

```
df.columns=df.columns+'b'
```

it does not work (I get the columns renamed to 'ab')
and neither does the following

```
df.columns=df.columns.tolist()+['b']
```

How to add a separate column 'b' to df, and `df.emtpy` keep on being `True`?

Using .loc is also not possible

```
   df.loc[:,'b']=None
```

as it returns

```
  Cannot set dataframe with no defined index and a scalar
```

Comment: df2=df.copy() followed by df2['b']=""  ?

Comment: actually it does. but why is '' not adding one element to the index then? and empty string is still a string

Comment: This is something I have been wondering myself...sorry but I don't know the answer!

Comment: `df['b'] = None` ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670/pandas-add-multiple-empty-columns-to-dataframe

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here are few ways to add an empty column to an empty dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
df['b'] = None
df = df.assign(c=None)
df = df.assign(d=df['a'])
df['e'] = pd.Series(index=df.index)   
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=list('f'))])
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e, f]
Index: []
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: See also `df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=['b']))` as per answer below.

Answer (score 20):

If you just do `df['b'] = None` then `df.empty` is still `True` and df is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

EDIT:
To create an empty `df2` from the columns of `df` and adding new columns, you can do:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns.tolist() + ['b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add multiple columns at the same time you can also reindex.

```
new_cols = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
df2 = df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols), axis=1)

#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [a, c, d, e, f, g]
#Index: []
```

Comment: Yeah, I like `union` better. It avoids the possibility of having two similarly named columns in the `df`

Comment: @piRSquared I think maybe using concat can conbine the `reindex` and `union`

Comment: @Wen I'm sure you're right.  However, that requires constructing a new dataframe simply to concat.  I tend to avoid constructing new pandas objects if it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way:

```
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=['b']))
```

The advantage of this method is you can add an arbitrary number of columns without explicit loops.

In addition, this satisfies your requirement of `df.empty` evaluating to `True` if no data exists.

Comment: Why do you have to copy?

Comment: @MrR, the question states: `for some reason I want to generate df2, another empty dataframe,`.

Comment: `df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=['b']))` is sufficient. No need for `df2 = df.copy()`

Comment: Upvoted. PS: This should be added to the first answer - it's missing from that nice compendium presented there, and it's one of the most elegant ways (if not the most elegant).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `concat`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
df
Out[568]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['b', 'c', 'd'])
pd.concat([df,df2])
Out[571]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d]
Index: []
```