# Pandas Python : how to create multiple columns from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list with columns to create :

```
new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3']
```

I want to create these columns in a dataframe and fill them with zero :

```
df[new_cols] = 0
```

Get error :

```
"['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3'] not in index"
```

which is true but unfortunate as I want to create them...

EDIT : This is a duplicate of this question : [Add multiple empty columns to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670) however I keep this one too because the accepted answer here was the simple solution I was looking for, and it was not he accepted answer out there

EDIT 2 : While the accepted answer is the most simple, interesting one-liner solutions were posted below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Add multiple empty columns to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670/pandas-add-multiple-empty-columns-to-dataframe)

Comment: As I see so many answers to this post. I suggest op to go to this link http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html to get a clear picture of how it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the columns one by one.

```
for col in new_cols:
    df[col] = 0
```

Also see the answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926670/pandas-add-multiple-empty-columns-to-dataframe/30926717) for other methods.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) by dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})
print (df)
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  a  3
4  b  4
5  b  5
6  b  6
7  c  7
8  d  8

new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3']
df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(new_cols, 0))
print (df)
   A  B  new_1  new_2  new_3
0  a  0      0      0      0
1  a  1      0      0      0
2  a  2      0      0      0
3  a  3      0      0      0
4  b  4      0      0      0
5  b  5      0      0      0
6  b  6      0      0      0
7  c  7      0      0      0
8  d  8      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([(0, 0, 0)], columns=new_cols)
```

Is this what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3']
values = [0, 0, 0]   # could be anything, also pd.Series

df = df.assign(**dict(zip(new_cols, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the column names before creating the column:

```
for col in new_cols:
    df[col] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Apply function to loop through the columns in the dataframe and assigning each of the element to a new field
for instance for a list in a dataframe with a list named keys

```
[10,20,30]
```

In your case since its all 0 we can directly assign them as 0 instead of looping through. But if we have values we can populate them as below
...

```
df['new_01']=df['keys'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['new_02']=df['keys'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['new_03']=df['keys'].apply(lambda x: x[2])
```