# Add column of empty lists to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Similar to this question [How to add an empty column to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe), I am interested in knowing the best way to add a column of empty lists to a DataFrame.

What I am trying to do is basically initialize a column and as I iterate over the rows to process some of them, then add a filled list in this new column to replace the initialized value.

For example, if below is my initial DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [5,6,7]}) # Sample DataFrame

>>> df
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
```

Then I want to ultimately end up with something like this, where each row has been processed separately (sample results shown):

```
>>> df
   a  b          c
0  1  5     [5, 6]
1  2  6     [9, 0]
2  3  7  [1, 2, 3]
```

Of course, if I try to initialize like `df['e'] = []` as I would with any other constant, it thinks I am trying to add a sequence of items with length 0, and hence fails.

If I try initializing a new column as `None` or `NaN`, I run in to the following issues when trying to assign a list to a location.

```
df['d'] = None

>>> df
   a  b     d
0  1  5  None
1  2  6  None
2  3  7  None
```

Issue 1 (it would be perfect if I can get this approach to work! Maybe something trivial I am missing):

```
>>> df.loc[0,'d'] = [1,3]

...
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Issue 2 (this one works, but not without a warning because it is not guaranteed to work as intended):

```
>>> df['d'][0] = [1,3]

C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Hence I resort to initializing with empty lists and extending them as needed. There are a couple of methods I can think of to initialize this way, but is there a more straightforward way?

Method 1:

```
df['empty_lists1'] = [list() for x in range(len(df.index))]

>>> df
   a  b   empty_lists1
0  1  5             []
1  2  6             []
2  3  7             []
```

Method 2:

```
 df['empty_lists2'] = df.apply(lambda x: [], axis=1)

>>> df
   a  b   empty_lists1   empty_lists2
0  1  5             []             []
1  2  6             []             []
2  3  7             []             []
```

**Summary of questions:**

Is there any minor syntax change that can be addressed in Issue 1 that can allow a list to be assigned to a `None`/`NaN` initialized field?

If not, then what is the best way to initialize a new column with empty lists?

Comment: in issue 1 and 2 you start refering to a column d.  what does that refer to?

Comment: and for what its worth i like approach 2.  pretty straightforward imo.

Comment: Column `'d'` is just a column of `None` or `NaN` initialized values, as defined just before the issues.

Comment: Is there any minor syntax change that can be addressed in issue 1 that could allow a list to be assigned to a `None`/`NaN` initialized field?

Comment: For issue 1: You can assign an (empty) list to a cell by using `df.at[0,'d'] = [1,3]`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

One more way is to use [`np.empty`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

```
df['empty_list'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
```

---

You could also knock off `.index` in your "Method 1" when trying to find `len` of `df`.

```
df['empty_list'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
```

---

Turns out, `np.empty` is faster...

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(1000000, 5))

In [3]: timeit df['empty1'] = pd.np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit df['empty2'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
10 loops, best of 3: 193 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit df['empty3'] = df.apply(lambda x: [], axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.89 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the `np.empty` approach does look faster. The `len(df.index)` also actually is similarly faster than just `len(df)`.

Comment: pd.np is deprecated. import and use np instead
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30489

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: the commenters caught the bug in my answer

```
s = pd.Series([[]] * 3)
s.iloc[0].append(1) #adding an item only to the first element
>s # unintended consequences:
0    [1]
1    [1]
2    [1]
```

So, the correct solution is

```
s = pd.Series([[] for i in range(3)])
s.iloc[0].append(1)
>s
0    [1]
1     []
2     []
```

<strike>OLD:</strike>

I timed all the three methods in the accepted answer, the fastest one took 216 ms on my machine. However, this took only 28 ms:

```
df['empty4'] = [[]] * len(df)
```

Note: Similarly, `df['e5'] = [set()] * len(df)` also took 28ms.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours, this solution is the real deal.

Comment: All these lists are the same object.  Setting one cell will set them all. df['empty_list'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]is better.

Comment: This is not correct, this assigns all rows to the same list reference, meaning if you append to one of the lists, it's not different from appending to them all at once - you need to initialize separate empty lists via a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

## Canonical solutions: List comprehension, `map` and `apply`

Obligatory disclaimer: avoid using lists in pandas columns where possible, list columns are slow to work with because they are objects and those are inherently hard to vectorize.

With that out of the way, here are the canonical methods of introducing a column of empty lists:

```
# List comprehension
df['c'] = [[] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
df

   a  b   c
0  1  5  []
1  2  6  []
2  3  7  []
```

There's also these shorthands involving `apply` and `map`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# map any column with defaultdict
df['c'] = df.iloc[:,0].map(defaultdict(list))
# same as,
df['c'] = df.iloc[:,0].map(lambda _: [])

# apply with defaultdict
df['c'] = df.apply(defaultdict(list), axis=1) 
# same as,
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda _: [], axis=1)

df

   a  b   c
0  1  5  []
1  2  6  []
2  3  7  []
```

---

#### Things you should NOT do

Some folks believe multiplying an empty list is the way to go, unfortunately this is wrong and will usually lead to hard-to-debug issues. Here's an MVP:

```
# WRONG
df['c'] = [[]] * len(df) 
df.at[0, 'c'].append('abc')
df.at[1, 'c'].append('def')
df

   a  b           c
0  1  5  [abc, def]
1  2  6  [abc, def]
2  3  7  [abc, def]
```

```
# RIGHT
df['c'] = [[] for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
df.at[0, 'c'].append('abc')
df.at[1, 'c'].append('def')
df

a  b      c
0  1  5  [abc]
1  2  6  [def]
2  3  7     []
```

In the first case, a single empty list is created and its *reference* is replicated across all the rows, so you see updates to one reflected to all of them. In the latter case each row is assigned its own empty list, so this is not a concern.