# Fill a dataframe column with empty arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to fill a pandas dataframe column with empty numpy arrays. I mean that any row has to be an empty array. Something like

```
df['ColumnName'] = np.empty(0,dtype=float)
```

but this don't work because it tries to use every value of the array and assign one value per row.

I tried then

```
for k in range(len(df)):
     df['ColumnName'].iloc[k] = np.empty(0,dtype=float)
```

but still no luck. Any advice ?

Comment: Now, what do you mean by `empty`? Have you read the docs on `np.empty`?

Comment: I mean that every row of the dataframe has to contain an array object, unitialisated and of zero length.

Comment: Do simple search before asking 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466769/add-column-of-empty-lists-to-dataframe

Comment: What's the intended use of this column? That kind of array is pretty useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add column of empty lists to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31466769/1278112)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the np.empty into number of rows and then assign them to the column. Since it aint a scalar it cant be directly assigned like `df['x'] = some_scalar`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2]})

df['c'] = [np.empty(0,dtype=float)]*len(df)
```

Output :

```
  a   c
0  0  []
1  1  []
2  2  []
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help. Dont forget to vote and accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple comprehension

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2]})
df['c'] = [[] for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output

```
   a   c
0  0  []
1  1  []
2  2  []
```