# Set all the values in multiple columns to empty lists pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, assign

I have a dataframe which have lists or values in their columns; something like the following:

```
df
     A        B        C      D
0   []      [3]    ['ON']     5
1   'a'   ['a']    ['ON']     5
2    5      [3]    ['ON']     5
3   []      [3]    ['ON']     5
...
```

I would like to replace all the values inside columns `A`, `B`, and `C` with empty lists. I tried using `.assign(column_name='value')` seperatly for the columns `A`, `B`, and `C`. I can set a value but I cannot set an empty list. I do not want to use `.apply(lambda x: [])`, since it is rather slow.

Is there any other way?

**Expected Outcome:**

```
df
     A    B    C    D
0   []   []   []    5
1   []   []   []    5
2   []   []   []    5
3   []   []   []    5
...
```

what I basically need isa pandas function which can do: `change everything in columns=['A','B','C'] to []`

Comment: Try checking ```numpy.empty```. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466769/add-column-of-empty-lists-to-dataframe) link here should help.  ```df['A'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()``` should work for column A, and similarly for the other columns you wish to apply it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['A'] = [np.empty(0,dtype=float)]*len(df)
df['B'] = [np.empty(0,dtype=float)]*len(df)
df['C'] = [np.empty(0,dtype=float)]*len(df)
```

---

Performance comparison:

for seed data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
for i in range(100):
    df = df.append({'A': i}, ignore_index=True)
df
```

**With 1 000 elements:** 396 µs vs 613 µs

[image]

**With 10 000 elements:** 1.06 ms vs 4.33 ms

[image]

**With 100 000 elements:** 8.87 ms vs 45.9 ms

[image]

Comment: If you make a comparison with the accepted answer, and show `np.empty` is faster than `[[]]*len(df)`, then I will accept this. Because for this I need to import numpy

Comment: @oakca - done, that answer was posted first :)

Comment: because of the benchmark, I accepted this

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['A'] = [[]]*len(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the column with a list comprehension.

E.g.

```
empty_col = [[] for x in range(len(df))]
df['A'] = empty_col
df['B'] = empty_col
df['C'] = empty_col
```

```
>>> df
         A    B    C    D
    0   []   []   []    5
    1   []   []   []    5
    2   []   []   []    5
    3   []   []   []    5
...
```