# Pandas adding empty column of objects to dataframe

Tags: pandas, object, dataframe

[How to add an empty column to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe#16327135)

This is partially covered already.

The `dtype of df["D"] = np.nan` in the accepted answer is `dtype=numpy.float64`.

Is there a way to initialize an empty list into each cell?

Tried `df["D"] = [[]] * len(df)` but all values are pointing to the same object and setting one to a value sets them all.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})
df

   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4


df["D"] = [[]] * len(df)
df
   A  B   D
0  1  2  []
1  2  3  []
2  3  4  []


df['D'][1].append(['a','b','c','d'])
df
   A  B               D
0  1  2  [[a, b, c, d]]
1  2  3  [[a, b, c, d]]
2  3  4  [[a, b, c, d]]
```

wanted

```
   A  B               D
0  1  2  []
1  2  3  [[a, b, c, d]]
2  3  4  []
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
df["D"] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
```

instead of

```
df["D"] = [[]] * len(df)
```

This way you'll create a different `[]` for each row.

---

Basically `[[] for _ in range(len(df))]` is a [list comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) It creates a `[]` for each value in `range(len(df))`.

This code has the same functionality as

```
l = []
for _ in range(len(df)):
    l.append([])
```

But is notably *faster*, *simpler* to write and even more readable.

If you want to know further on list comprehensions , I'd recommend [the answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list).

If you want to know further on *why that behavior* happens when doing `[[]] * len(df)`, I'd recommend [the answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Thanks this did work, could you explain what you did for my understanding please?

Comment: @Joylove Sure :) I've edited

Comment: The underscore is just a name of a variable. Could have been `i`, `j` or any other name. It is just a convention to name the variable `_` if you are not going to use it

Comment: Which line raises this warning? `df["D"] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]` will not raise this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just pass in a list of lists when creating the column. Then assign the list value to a temporary variable, next assign that list to one field in the data frame using loc

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col A'] = [1,12,312,352]
df['col B'] = [[],[],[],[]]

ser = [1,4,5,6]
df.loc[2,'col B'] = ser
df
```

Output:

[image: Click Here to View Image]

Does this help? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: sorry updated a line, found a typo

Comment: The df is varying in number of rows as I loop through my code, so in your example df['col B'] could not be initialized with a fixed length of data.

Comment: Then using the code @RafaelC suggest would work best then for when you intialize the column. Yes?

Comment: Awesome. cheers