# Is the time complexity for pandas inner, left and right joins O(n)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I read in this thread:

[What is the running time (big "O" order) of pandas DataFrame.join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715082/what-is-the-running-time-big-o-order-of-pandas-dataframe-join)

that an inner join is expected to be O(n), whereas a left and right join are expected to be O(n log n). I have been doing some testing using random dataframes such as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'user_id': range(1, size + 1),  # Unique user_id for df1
        'numeric_1': np.random.rand(size),
        'numeric_2': np.random.rand(size),
        'numeric_3': np.random.rand(size),
        'string_1': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], size),
        'string_2': np.random.choice(['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], size),
        'string_3': np.random.choice(['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], size),
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'user_id': range(size + 1, 2 * size + 1),  # Ensuring unique user_id for df2
        'numeric_4': np.random.rand(size),
        'numeric_5': np.random.rand(size),
        'numeric_6': np.random.rand(size),
        'string_4': np.random.choice(['M', 'N', 'O', 'P'], size),
        'string_5': np.random.choice(['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'], size),
        'string_6': np.random.choice(['U', 'V', 'W', 'X'], size),
    })
```

I ran several simulations for each sample size and averaged the results in order to reduce the impact of variations due to local conditions on the computer. This is the plot I obtained:

[image]

Since all 3 lines are close to parallel, and linear (with slope around 1.07) I took this to mean that all 3 join types are O(n^1.07) which is very nearly O(n). Does this seem correct ? What should I see in the plot if left/right joins were O(n log n) instead ?

Happy to share my complete code, if requested.

Comment: The linked answer says `O(n logn)` is for sorting the left/right index/key. If your index/key is already sorted (quick sort???), then the join operation is `O(n)`. Also, IIRC `left/right` joins now just retain the original of the left/right key without sorting, in which case, they're also `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since all 3 lines are close to parallel, and linear (with slope around 1.07) I took this to mean that all 3 join types are O(n^1.07) which is very nearly O(n). Does this seem correct ?

if you look closely at the 3 lines in your plot, the slope of line for "inner" becomes slightly smaller than the slopes for "left" and "right" for larger n, which is consistent with the inner join being O(n) and the left/right joins being O(n log n), however this is very marginal - all 3 joins are very close to O(n). If left/right really are O(n log n) I would expect further divergence, and we may observe this if the sample sizes were increased even further.

> What should I see in the plot if left/right joins were O(n log n) instead ?

I would suggest running a simulation to investigate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate an extremely large range of sample sizes
n = np.logspace(1, 10, 10000)  # From 10^1 to 10^10
time_linear = n  # O(n)
time_nlogn = n * np.log(n)  # O(n log n)

# Plotting on a log-log scale using the updated API
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.loglog(n, time_linear, label='O(n)', base=10)
plt.loglog(n, time_nlogn, label='O(n log n)', base=10, linestyle='--')

plt.xlabel('Input size (n)')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Time Complexity: O(n) vs. O(n log n) on a Log-Log Scale')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True, which="both", linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

which produces this:
[image]

If you were to plot the same functions on a linear scale, the difference between O(n) and O(n log n) would be even more apparent, especially for large n, where the log n factor would cause the O(n log n) plot to grow noticeably faster than the O(n) plot.

For example, with a small change to the code above we can see what a linear-linear and a log-linear plot would look like:

[image]

And for log-linear:
[image]