# two problem in dealing with my csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

**1)** Sort the headers(columns) while creating a CSV file

**2)** Add a new header(column) in a CSV file

For the 1st problem, I have some CSV files, each of them has a column, then I merge these CSV files together. In the final CSV file, the headers are not in the right order.

The correct order should be `a, b, c...` but the final CSV file has the header `c, b, a`. How can I sort the headers?

```
    # create final csv file iteration
    for i in range(lenList - 1):
        newcsv = pd.read_csv(csv_list[i + 1])
        csv_out = newcsv.merge(oldcsv, on=['Time'], how="outer", sort=True)
        oldcsv = csv_out

    # saves the final csv file
    output_file = "../build/*.csv"
    oldcsv.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

For the 2nd problem, When I create CSV files, some 18 columns, and somehave 17 columns. But they should both have 18 columns.

E.g, file1 has columns `a, b, c, d`.file2 has columns `a,b,c`.

I need them to have same number of colums. So I need to add an empty column to file2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the order of the columns, using `use_cols` as a parameter to `read_csv`:

> **usecols** : list-like or callable, default None
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
>   be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or
>   strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in
>   names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a
>   valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or [‘foo’, ‘bar’,
>   ‘baz’]. Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1,
>   0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved
>   use pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for
>   columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
>   'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
>   column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
>   True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
>   much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

As far as the empty column, you can [add an empty column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe)

Comment: OK! You are very helpful! Thanks a lot!