# How to reindex a pandas dataframe within a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I'm trying to add column headers with empty values to my dataframe ([just like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405540/8472786)), but within a function that is already modifying it, like so:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame()

def myfunc(df):
  df['newcol1'] = np.nan  # this works

  list_of_newcols = ['newcol2', 'newcol3']
  df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist() + list_of_newcols)  # this does not
  return
myfunc(mydf)
```

If I run the lines individually in an IPython console, it will add them. But run as a script, newcol1 will be added but 2 and 3 will not. Setting `copy=False` does not work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) produces a new object unless the indexes are equivalent, so you will need to return the new object from your function.

```
def myfunc(df):
  df['newcol1'] = np.nan  # this works

  list_of_newcols = ['newcol2', 'newcol3']
  df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist + list_of_newcols)  # this does not
  return df

mydf = myfunc(mydf)
```

Comment: So the only scenario where the indexes would be equivalent is if I was rearranging existing column labels?

Comment: @ExcelHelp I believe so, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Actually no - a copy is returned unless the requested index is actually equal to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the mistake you made with the actual code or while you were typing it in here, but the `tolist()` is a function and you must add the brackets.

```
df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist() + list_of_newcols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `NaN` values and specify *again* new column labels. You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with an arbitrary list of strings; `NaN` is the default value where data is not specified.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})

df = df.reindex(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

print(df)

   A   B   C
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2 NaN NaN
2  3 NaN NaN
```