# How to select columns and generate Nan values for non-existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that contains a list of target columns:

```
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col4"]
```

Then I have several pandas DataFrames with a different number of columns. I must select columns from `cols`. If one of the columns from `cols` does not exist in a DataFrame, then NaN values should be generated.

```
df1 =
col1  col3
1     x1
2     x2
3     x3

df2 =
col1  col2  col4
1     f1    car3
3     f2    car2
4     f5    car1
```

For example, `df2[cols]` works well, but `df1[cols]` obvioulsy fails. I need the following output for `df1`

```
df1 =
col1  col2  col3
1     NaN   NaN
2     NaN   NaN
3     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an empty column to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with list of columns, if no matched are added `NaN`s columns:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df1)
   col1  col2  col4
0     1   NaN   NaN
1     2   NaN   NaN
2     3   NaN   NaN
```

So for `df2` are returned same columns:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df2)
   col1 col2  col4
0     1   f1  car3
1     3   f2  car2
2     4   f5  car1
```