# Python: Make Each Element in List a New Column in Existing Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, element, concatenation

I have an existing sample data frame (see below).

```
A   B
as  2
df  32
fj  1
```

I also have two sample lists:

```
list_1 = ['234', '341', '482']
list_2 = ['111', '2223', '8908']
```

I want to concat my two lists with my dataframe so that each element in the list is a column.

Desired output:

```
A   B   234   341   482   111   2223   8908
as  2
df  32
fj  1
```

I've scoured Google on how to do this but could not find anything specific.

Comment: What should be the values contained in the new columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an empty column to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe)

Comment: Did you find anything unspecific? Did you try it? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html?highlight=assign#pandas.DataFrame.assign) function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['as', 2],
    ['df', 32],
    ['fj', 1]
])
list_1 = ['234', '341', '482']
list_2 = ['111', '2223', '8908']
df
```

```
    0   1
0   as  2
1   df  32
2   fj  1
```

---

```
df = df.assign(**{k: 0 for k in list_1 + list_2})
df
```

```
    0   1   111     2223    234     341     482     8908
0   as  2   0       0       0       0       0       0
1   df  32  0       0       0       0       0       0
2   fj  1   0       0       0       0       0       0
```