# How to solve KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") in this case (Pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a CSV file for example like this :

| id | name | email | physics | chemistry | maths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com | 67 | 78 | 90 |
| 2 | Danny | dany@example.com | 77 | 98 | 89 |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com | 77 | 67 | 90 |

Now I want to output a new CSV file using pandas which has new columns too for example like this :

| id | name | grade | address | physics | chemistry | attendance | maths | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to create new columns in random places and I want to place the value as blank in the new columns.

I have tried using :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
final_df = df.loc[['id','name','grade','address','physics','chemistry','attendance','maths','total']]
```

When I did this I got an error :

```
KeyError(f“None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]”)
```

Any ideas or suggestions to arrange this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new columns you should try `reindex` with `axis=1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
final_df = df.reindex(['id','name','grade','address','physics','chemistry','attendance','maths','total'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have your dataframe already, we use the Code you provided:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
```

Your extra columns should be stored in a list, this makes your Code easier to write and easier to understand.

```
additional_cols = ['grade','address','attendance','total']
```

The best way to add multiple columns is reindex like U11-Forward suggested.

```
mydf = df.reindex(df.columns.tolist() + additional_cols, axis = 1)
```

A similar question has been asked here[1]: [How to add an empty column to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327055/how-to-add-an-empty-column-to-a-dataframe)

Regarding your error, the documentation helps you with that: The loc method is used to access elements and not to create them. If an element is not accessible a key error is returned.