# Merging two dataframes in Pandas/Python keeping all columns from dataframe 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe **1** is a empty dataframe intended to set the "headers" of the columns:

| Header Green | Header Yellow | Header Red |
| --- | --- | --- |

Dataframe **2** holds the actual rows, but some of the columns might be different from dataframe 1.

| Header Green | Header Yellow | Header Purple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data Green | Data Yellow | Data Purple |

In the resulting dataframe, I want to stack the two dataframes on top of each other, but only keeping the columnes that are in dataframe1 (that is Green,Yellow,Red). The final dataframe should then be:

| Header Green | Header Yellow | Header Red |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data Green | Data Yellow | Blank |

Just to be clear, the final table:

1 Keeps all the columns from dataframe 1

2 Add the data from dataframe 2 where the columns are the same as dataframe 1

3 Drops any column from dataframe 2 that is not in datafram 1 in the final dataframe.

Unfortunately there is a lot of columns in the dataframes, so the solution needs to understand which columns to keep without being given anything else then the existing name in the dataframes.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need any data from dataframe 1? If that's the case, just make a list of columns from dataframe 2 that are in dataframe 1: `cols_to_keep = [col for col in df2.columns if col in df1.columns]` and then use that column list to select from dataframe 2: `df_new = df1[cols_to_keep]`

Comment: Thanks, manage to do that, but that means that df_new does not hold all the columnes from df1 with blank values where the colume is not in df2. So in the above, with this solution i would not get Header Red in the resulting dataframe?

Comment: ah, got it. missed the fact that you needed the columns with empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here using `df.reindex` actually does exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43995812/9357244

```
df_new = df2.reindex(columns = df.columns)
```

Will keep columns in `df2` if they are columns in `df`. Any missing columns will be instantiated as null values.

Comment: Thank you so much, this absolutly did the trick. Just as an example, the following code do what i intended: import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"])
data={"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4],"d":[5,7]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_new = df2.reindex(columns = df1.columns)
print(df_new)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the dataset is massive, I feel like this would solve your problem:

Just concatenate and slice after

```
pd.concat([df,df2])[df.columns]
```